# Proteger el acceso a rutas

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

Quiero saber como hacer que después de registrarse el usuario sea redireccionado y solo los usuarios con cuenta puedan entrar a esa pantalla este es mi server.js de nodejs

```js
var yo = require('yo-yo');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var $ = require('jquery');
var urldescarga = '';
var archivo = '';

$(document).ready(function(){

  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var database = firebase.database();
  var ref = database.ref("/");
  var usersRef = ref.child("users");
  var storageService = firebase.storage();

  $('#btn_send').on('change', function(evento) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(evento.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = function(){
     let preview = document.getElementById('preview'),
     image = document.createElement('img');

     image.src = reader.result;

     preview.innerHTML = '';
     preview.append(image);
   };

   evento.preventDefault();
   archivo  = evento.target.files[0];
 });
  
  $('#registerForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      email: $('#email').val(), //get the email from Form
      username: $('#username').val(), // get firstName
    };
    var passwords = {
      password : $('#password').val(), //get the pass from Form
      cpassword : $('#copassword').val(), //get the pass from Form

    }
    if( data.email != '' && passwords.password != ''  && passwords.cpassword != '' ){
      if ( passwords.password == passwords.cpassword ) {

        firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, passwords.password)
        .catch(function(error) {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          alert(errorMessage)
        })

        .then(function(user) {
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            var newalias = data.username
            var refStorage = storageService.ref('users-photo-profile').child(archivo.name);
            var uploadTask = refStorage.put(archivo);
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', null,
              function(error){
                console.log('Error al subir el archivo', error);
              },
              function(){
                alert('usuario registrado')
                alert('Foto de perfil establecida');
                uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                  urldescarga = downloadURL
                  upall();
                });
              });

            if (user) { 
              console.log(user)
              function upall() {
               user.updateProfile({
                displayName: newalias,
                photoURL: urldescarga
              })
               .then(function() {
                usersRef.child(user.uid).set({
                  username: newalias,
                  email: data.email,
                  photo: urldescarga
                })
                console.log(user.displayName, user.uid, user.photoURL)
              })
               .catch(function(error) {
                var errorc = error.code;
                var errorM = error.message;
                alert(errorM)
              });
             }
           }
         });
        })

      }
      else {
        alert('Contraseña no coincide')
      }
    }

  })});
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
  res.render('dash');
});

app.get('/signin', function(req, res){
  res.render('dash');
});

app.listen(3000, function (err) {
 if (err) console.log("error en el servidor"), process.exit(1);
 console.log('server running')

})
```

Comment: Para lograr lo que te propones, debes implementar una forma de manejo de sesión. Puedes hacerlo mediante cookies o mediante un token. Luego, para protejer tus rutas debes implementar un middleware que verifique el estado de la sesión, ya sea leyendo la cookie o solicitando el token. Esto es a grosso modo. Puedes leer [¿Cómo implementar autenticación basada en Token?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/carlosazaustre.es/autenticacion-con-token-en-node-js/amp/) como una guía básica para que puedas implementar lo que te propones. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras muchas gracias!!! has aclarado mis dudas